# Function inside IIFE not working correctly

Tags: javascript

I have a `console.log` inside a function in an IIFE that is not working (doesnt show the "id").

The `console.log` outside the IIFE is working correctly.

I can't find where is the problem.

```
(function () {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContenLoaded", () => {
        const paramsURL = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

        const customerId = parseInt(paramsURL.get("id"));

        console.log(customerId);
    });
})();

console.log(window.location.search)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is related to a typo. It is `DOMContentLoaded` not `DOMContenLoaded`.

```
(function () {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        const paramsURL = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

        const customerId = parseInt(paramsURL.get("id"));

        console.log(customerId);
    });
})();

console.log(window.location.search)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an IIFE, this would simply work.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContenLoaded", () => {
    const paramsURL = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const customerId = parseInt(paramsURL.get("id"));
    console.log(customerId);
});
```

Comment: Thanks (typo in "DOMContentLoaded")